# how to reconstruct the image from histogram in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The following code convert the image into histogram, but now i want to reconstruct the image from the histogram. how can i do it?

```
a = imread('picture.jpg');
subplot(2,2,1);
image(a);

c=rgb2gray(a);
subplot(2,2,2);
imhist(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am new to the subject as well, but according to my understanding histogram of an image gives you the frequency/count of different intensity levels(bins). As good as that is, without the knowledge of where to put those intensities values(individual pixel location) while recreating the image it is mostly unlikely to recreate the original image from only the histogram. You can refer to [this link](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/314046?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) fro more clarification.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Many different images might have same histograms. Or let's say I have an image and I randomly changed the locations of pixels in the image. Both images will have same histograms. So you can't reconstruct the image from its histogram. It is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

without any additional knowledge about the image you simply **can not** reconstruct original image only from histogram. If you assume 8 bit gray-scale image then histogram is just set of 256 numbers holding the occurrence of each gray-scale intensity. Does not matter what resolution you got it will be still the same set so you are loosing too much information. Also histograms are usually invariant on rotation, scale, offset so you do not have any of the info encoded in them either ...

However you can use histogram to chose from predefined images (sometimes it is used for classification and image comparison). For example if you got set of images in some database and you know your image is one of them then sometimes histogram is enough to chose the correct one ...

There are also other then just color/gray-scale histograms out there but the point still stands. If you loose to much information you simply do not have enough to reconstruct back ...

If you got more information about the image like pixel counts per col/roe etc and you know some other geometric and or physical properties of the content then may be you can reconstruct but not just with histogram.

Answer (score 1):

A histogram just tells us how many times each intensity value occurred in the image but not where the intensity values are actually present in the image,
So we can't reconstruct an image from its histogram.

In other words:
different images (A, B, ...) may have the same histogram H; we do not know which image comes from histogram H.